# Tronxy X5S-400 Marlin stuck at splash-screen

Tags: marlin, firmware

I got a Tronxy X5S-400, I assembled it and when I power it on, I see on the screen one of the below images and gets stuck there.

Is the firmware broken? If yes, where can I get a `configuration.h` file?

I verified that the two buses between the screen and the mainboard are not loose or incorrectly connected.

[image: Marlin splash screen]

[image: Screen corruption]

The board is a MKS Melzi v2.0 clone

[image: Controller]

Comment: Just contact the seller, don't mess with it as this appears to be a dead on arrival (DOA). The seller will come up with a solution, either compensation or a new board. This will only work when you have not tampered with the hardware or software.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looked like the firmware wasn't flashed correctly in the factory. What I did was to flash a bootloader using an Arduino compatible board and to flash the Marlin software e.g. according to [videos from this guy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3gwWVFtdg-4).

Next, the menu wasn't displayed correctly so I added, in the `Configuration.h` the following lines:

```
#define ST7920_DELAY_1 DELAY_NS(63)
#define ST7920_DELAY_2 DELAY_NS(100)
#define ST7920_DELAY_3 DELAY_NS(125)
```

Now the display is working fine, and the Marlin firmware can be directly flashed from the computer because the bootloader remains there.

I also had a problem with the heating bed which was heating very slow and I had to raise consistently the `TEMP_BED_RESIDENCY_TIME` and decrease `TEMP_BED_HYSTERESIS` to 1.

Answer (score 1):

If the controller is one of Tronxy's new Chitu boards, you will not have the option of recompiling the firmware, since they are locked down. Apart from checking that the PSU is delivering the correct voltage, your only option may be to request a new main board from the vendor.

Comment: It's not Chitu, it's this one https://www.picclickimg.com/d/l400/pict/163564914630_/Tronxy-X5-X5S-3D-Printer-Controller-Mainboard.jpg

Comment: @yonutix OK. That's basically a Melzi (I think). I don't know much about the bigger Tronxy printers (I'm an X1 user). There is a very good Facebook user group that will give you the answers that you need: https://www.facebook.com/groups/1119103791478149. You should be able to get config files (and pre-compiled firmware) there.

Comment: It doesn't look like a [Melzi](https://reprap.org/wiki/Melzi), whoops sorry yes, it's a [Melzi MKS v2.0 clone](https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1wHPxRpXXXXbVXXXXq6xXFXXXv/MKS-MELZI-V2-0-RepRap-controller-motherboard-circuit-PCB-3d-printing-mainboard-good-for-Prusa-i3.jpg_640x640.jpg)

Comment: Ok, I got it, I flashed the  bootloader, the firmware and I modified some configuration.h defines

Comment: Hi @yonutix , could you post your comment `Ok, I got it, I flashed the bootloader, the firmware and I modified some configuration.h defines` as an answer (maybe expanding upon it as well, if possible) and mark it as accepted. That way your question will no longer be in the unanswered list.  As we are a beta site we'd like to keep the unanswered questions to a minimum in order to graduate. Thanks .